# reading blank excel cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read one excel file..but it contains some blank cells as well..[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLxBo.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tehfm.png i want to read these rows as 1234567890,,aaaaaaaaaa
:1234567891,aaaaaaaaab,aaaaaaaaab:1234567892,aaaaaaaaac,aaaaaaaaac.....means i want to separate cells with comma and rows with colon and if there is a blank cell than i want to add one space there...i wirte this code but its not working[image]

Comment: post code and not screenshots...

Comment: this is the code i have written while posting it shows some errors thats y i took a screen shot

Comment: people could test your code if they want to check something when you post it as text. Nobody is going to bother retyping it from a screenshot.

Comment: Take help from http://stackoverflow.com/a/23368105/624003

Answer (score 1):

Using  the Java Excel library from the webpage http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

I have tested the code with a sample file and it works fine.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class ReadExcel
{
    private String inputFile;

    public void setInputFile(String inputFile)
    {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException
    {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w;

        try
        {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);

            // Loop over first 10 column and lines
            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getRows(); j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < sheet.getColumns(); i++)
                {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i,j);
                    CellType type = cell.getType();


                    if (type == CellType.LABEL)
                    {
                        System.out.print(cell.getContents() + ", ");
                    }
                    if (type == CellType.NUMBER)
                    {
                        System.out.print(cell.getContents() + ", ");
                    }
                    if (type == CellType.EMPTY)   
                    {
                        System.out.print(", ");
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (BiffException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ReadExcel test = new ReadExcel();
        test.setInputFile("c:/temporary/lars.xls");
        test.read();

    }
}
```