# Passing FileName dynamically when fetching Data? Selenium -java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, apache-poi

when i pass the file name like this, it doesn't fetch the data..what to do for passing the fileName dynamically in the method ?

```
    public static String fetchData(int index,int rowNum, int cellNum,String FileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File filePath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/InEdge_Files/ExcelData/" + FileName + ".xlsx");
        fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
        value = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).getStringCellValue();
        return value;

    }
```

...When passing the Data i use, driver.get(fetchData(0,1,2,"Data");

Comment: Why `driver.get`? it is used to navigate to a url. Please paste your entire code.

Comment: As shank087 says, driver.get serves to navigate to URL. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361379/fetch-the-data-from-excel-using-apache-poi-using-java, how to fetch data from xls(x).

Comment: @shank087  yes.. I'm passing the URL from an Excel File, so if there are two excel files, I need to pass the fileName when I'm fetching data.. is that possible like that..

Answer (score 0):

```
String urlToOpen = fetchData(0,1,2,"Data");
driver.navigate().to(urlToOpen);
```